# Packager for Html + js +css

Tags: javascript, html, package, extjs, packaging

How can I zip/pack a bunch of html, js and css files together so that whenever a person click on that zip file, chrome and local server start on that machine and some particular file will be loaded on the first screen...any ideas

Answer (score 1):

Simple!

1. Combine all your HTML files into one.
2. uuencode all your media assets and add them to CSS.
3. Convert all the CSS to inline CSS in the single HTML file.
4. Copy all the JS into the same HTML file.

You now have a package with everything in it, and since it's got an html file extension, it will launch the browser when you double-click it.

(I recommend you write a script to do this, and share it with all of us.)

Comment: Do you know any tools for this?

Answer (score 0):

You might have to create an auto executing .exe file in the zip file that runs after it's un-zipped.

You'd probably be better off with a "README.TXT" file in there, as the auto .exe is sketchy (and virus like) - it may also be snagged and quarantined by anti-virus

Comment: how to make that .exe file and start the server.??